# Running interactive job with port forwarding on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, port, kubectl

I want to run an interactive exploratory job on kubernetes. AFAIU, the simplest way to do it, is to use kubectl run. However, I can't find an easy way to setup local port forwarding in one command (like ssh port forwarding). Is there any good way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need it to be one command? Won't `kubectl port-forward ... &; kubectl exec ...` work just fine?

Comment: Having said that, your idea of port-forwarding along with exec does sound like a nice one, so I would encourage you to [file a feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new?template=enhancement.md) with kubernetes; you might also be interested in the [reverse port-forward issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20227)

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I create one https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71643

Answer (score 0):

The feature of local port forwarding in Kubernetes is on promise, function requests have been already raised:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71643 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20227